# database connection string

Tags: python

не пойму, что вписать вместо "your_db_connection_string". Сама строка кода: db_connection_string = "your_db_connection_string". Датасет скачен на пк, и есть на гугл коллаб, собственно я там и работаю.

Comment: Ну это ещё смотря какая БД. Нужно от этого плясать. Для конкретной БД нужно смотреть строку соединения примеры.

Comment: Подразумевается, что у вас какая-то база данных, в которую вы загрузили датасет. Это может быть sqlite в простейшем случае. Дальше уже в зависимости от базы данных указывается строка подключения.

Answer (score 0):

[Строка подключения](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F), специальный формат строки, который используется для подключения к БД. Нужно либо подключится например sqlite будет так: `db_connection_string = "sqlite:///path_to_your_database.db"`, либо просто в коде указать путь до файла если он лежит в виде файла.